# CAML query retrieve all items from a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, caml-query, caml

I have a JavaScript piece of code that I use to retrieve list item from SharePoint by selected options from drop-down list. Depending the selection it would assign a value to a CAMLQuery variable.

Option 1 (filters by Office):

```
CAMLQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Regional_x0020_Office' /><Value Type='Text'>" + regionalOffice + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
```

Option 2 (filters by Year):

```
CAMLQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' /><Value Type='Text'>" + fiscalYear + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
```

Option 3 (All items):

```
CAMLQuery = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>"
```

Everything works perfectly, except Option 3, which is the one I would like to use to show all Items. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect because you've wrapped the Query with a View node in option 3, it isn't present in the other 2 working examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add View Tag, reform the query as follows:

```
CAMLQuery = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a null check:

```
CAMLQuery = "<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' /></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mentioned that I've done that already and no luck.

Comment: OK. I have edited my answer. Try adding a null check in there

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps its the default `RowLimit` that is causing you to not retrieve all results? A `RowLimit` of 0 will return all results. For example:

```
"<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Fiscal_x0020_Year\" Ascending=\"TRUE\"></FieldRef></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>0</RowLimit></View>"
```

Also, the following information from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms428643(v=office.14).aspx is worth noting regarding RowLimit:

> If Paged is not TRUE and the row limit is exceeded, the server renders a RowLimitExceeded element in the view if this element is specified. Otherwise, the default behavior is to give no indication to the user that the row limit has been exceeded.